# Call remote urls by many users simultaneously (realtime)

Tags: php

What is the best way (in PHP) to get the page title and metatag contents of potentially millions of remote URLs in realtime?

also, is this feasible to accomplish using a single shared server?

So far I'm looking into 4 possibilities. (I'm also using Codeigniter)

[fOpen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do millions in real time on a shared server. You'll very likely get shutdown for using too much CPU. But if you are using PHP, your best bet would be to use multi-curl. See a very similar question, which contains code sample:

[Status checker for hundreds IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956839/status-checker-for-hundreds-ip-addresses/8956949#8956949)

Comment: how does node.js stack up in this scenario?

Comment: I haven't tried node for something like this, but node seems to perform pretty awesome for most things I've tried with it. Node should also have smaller memory requirements, and perhaps less CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

It depends  of your purpose. Actually in any case you should use asynchronous approach. In PHP you can try to use curl  with async sockets or pcntl extension (form cgi mode). 
Or you can use so popular now node.js too (but it's not a PHP at all :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). With this DOM Parser you will get the whole page content and parse the head title and meta tags.

Comment: with "PHP simple html dom" parser for million pages you will not have enough memory.